# How to add ipv4 capability to ipv6-only-vserver?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, ipv6, ssh-tunnel, ipv4

I have an ipv6-only-vserver and a dual stack (ipv4-ipv6) server. How do I "add" ipv4 capability to the ipv6-only-server? So it's possible to "use" it like a ipv4 server:

- ssh/scp into the vserver via ipv4
- using webdav/sftp/http/xmpp/... via ipv4
- use curl on github/gitlab/ other ipv4 websites

The hosting company does not have an ipv4 gateway, proxy or similar - only ipv6.

Added: I do have a dual-stack (IPv4, IPv6) server where I setup an OpenVPN server and also connected the ipv6-only-vserver as client, but the performance was horrible (latency 10x times higher ~1.200ms and speed 4mbits up/ 8mbits down ... but without vpn 600mbits up / 750mbits down).

---

I looked into several tools (`socat`  `6tunnel` `sshuttle`), but couldn't make it work, except the ssh which is working:

`/etc/rc.local
nohup socat TCP4-LISTEN:XXXXX,fork,su=nobody TCP6:[IPv6-DUALSTACK-SERVER]:22`

Answer (score -1):

Your choice of [IPv6 transition mechanisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_transition_mechanism).

DNS64 + NAT64 is common for v6 hosts to access v4.

v4 to v6 can be tricky in that the v6 only host doesn't have its own v4 address; that's the whole point. Consider tunneling to give your v4 only hosts v6. Such as 6in4 or a dual stack VPN.

---

Or, you can get native v6. Insist your service providers and your network are v6 ready. Demand services you use have a plan for going v6, and provide this use case.

Comment: I really need a technical answer, because I can't set it up myself. In fact I already setup a OpenVPN server on the dual-stack and connected the ipv6-only-vserver, but the latency was 10x higher and the up/download speed was 2mbits / 8mbits (with no VPN: 400mbits / 750mbits).

Comment: That you have a VPN is useful information, please edit your question to add that and your performance requirement. And please elaborate what you mean by "can't set it up yourself". Do you not have privileges on the dual stack server? That's going to make it difficult to install NAT64 software.

Comment: They are both my servers (full root access). I couldn't set it up, because I don't know how to do it. Unfortunately I couldn't find any tutorial for it.